# How to reduce the running time and memory utilization of the Louvain algorithm in the Neo4j Graph?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

This is my data:
[Neo4j data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eOvE.png)

This is the CQL:

```
"call algo.louvain.stream('','',{weightProperty: 'weight'}) YIELD nodeId,community return algo.getNodeById(nodeId).mno as name ,community","/mno-rel.csv",{});
```

This is the neo4j config:

- dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=71440m
- dbms.memory.heap.max_size=71440m
- dbms.memory.pagecache.size=20g

Neo4j version : neo4j-community-3.5.8

When I run the above algorithm, it will take me 5 hours and take more than 70 g of memory.

Please help me how to reduce memory and time. I appreciate it very much :D

==========================================================================

Answer logisima's question:

Total Store Size : 60.71 GiB

CPU(s) : 40

> total used free shared buff/cache available
>
> Mem: 125G 114G 1.4G 337M 9.7G 9.8G

debug.log
20-02-05 23:52:54.946+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.VmPauseMonitorComponent] Detected VM stop-the-world pause: {pauseTime=3882, gcTime=21, gcCount=1}

2020-02-05 23:53:05.327+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] [algo-1] Louvain 0% round 3

2020-02-05 23:53:15.327+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] [algo-2] Louvain 77% round 3

2020-02-05 23:53:25.385+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] [algo-3] Louvain 10% round 4

2020-02-05 23:53:35.378+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] [algo-1] Louvain 90% round 4

2020-02-05 23:53:45.379+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] [algo-4] Louvain 26% round 5

2020-02-05 23:53:59.480+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] [neo4j.BoltWorker-4 [bolt] [/10.3.99.111:49607] ] Louvain 100% level: 7 communities: 7689984 q: 0.9808712031807056

2020-02-05 23:54:03.543+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.VmPauseMonitorComponent] Detected VM stop-the-world pause: {pauseTime=197, gcTime=202, gcCount=1}

2020-02-05 23:54:07.130+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.VmPauseMonitorComponent] Detected VM stop-the-world pause: {pauseTime=184, gcTime=243, gcCount=1}

2020-02-05 23:54:21.578+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] [algo-2] Louvain 0% round 1

2020-02-05 23:54:23.528+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.VmPauseMonitorComponent] Detected VM stop-the-world pause: {pauseTime=366, gcTime=380, gcCount=1}

2020-02-05 23:54:26.352+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.VmPauseMonitorComponent] Detected VM stop-the-world pause: {pauseTime=121, gcTime=217, gcCount=1}

2020-02-05 23:54:31.579+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] [algo-1] Louvain 80% round 1

2020-02-05 23:54:40.056+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.VmPauseMonitorComponent] Detected VM stop-the-world pause: {pauseTime=5693, gcTime=0, gcCount=0}

2020-02-05 23:54:41.580+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] [algo-2] Louvain 98% round 1

2020-02-05 23:54:47.314+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] [neo4j.BoltWorker-4 [bolt] [/10.3.99.111:49607] ] Louvain 100% level: 8 communities: 7689984 q: -1.0

2020-02-05 23:55:11.177+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.VmPauseMonitorComponent] Detected VM stop-the-world pause: {pauseTime=5269, gcTime=0, gcCount=0}

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a louvain on your entire graph, ie. on all your node's type and relationships.

I'm not sure it's a good idea because you don't have homogeneous graph, and so generally such a result is not relevant (depends of the data and the use-case).

That's why in the graph algo there a system to created a projected graph if it's needed.

For the optimisation, can you respond to thoses questions :

- What is size (in Gb) of your database (`:sysinfo` in the browser)
- How many CPU/Core do you have ?
- How many RAM do you have ?
- Is there something in `debug.log`

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I updated the results at the end of the problem description :D

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are aware, but try out the [Neo4j Graph Data Science library](https://github.com/neo4j/graph-data-science). It is the successor of the graph algorithms library, which is deprecated, and should have better performance. Looking at the additional data you provided it seems that the bottleneck is not the Louvain algorithm, but actually writing the results back to a CSV file. Maybe you could try to write back the results to Neo4j and then fetch results parallel from Neo4j using APOC.